# Need to add class to font awesome icon (child of a link) in AJAX response

Tags: jquery, ajax, font-awesome

I am using AJAX to allow users to bookmark a link when the bookmark icon is clicked, the AJAX works fine but I want to add class (the color green) to the font awesome bookmark icon once a successful response is returned. I tried various techniques but none are working.

```
<ul>
<li class="base-text gray-2 p-2">
<a href="#" class="bookmark" id="bookmark-1" data-id="1" data-type="FT" data-link="abc123">
<i id="bm-1" class="fa-solid fa-bookmark gray" rel="tooltip" title="Bookmark"></i></a></li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() 
  {
    $('.bookmark').click(function(){
      var bkid     = $(this).attr("data-id");
      var link     = $(this).attr("data-link");
      var bktyp    = $(this).attr("data-type");
      var bookmark = $(this);
      var token    = $("input[name=<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>").val();

      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
        url:  '<?php echo base_url('bookmark');?>',
        data: {'<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>' : token, 'bmktyp' : bktyp, 'link' : link},
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(data)
        {
          $('input[name="fmpfy_tk"]').val(data.csrf);
          if(data.response == 'on')
          {
            bookmark.find("i").removeClass('gray');
            bookmark.find("i").addClass('success_green');
          }
          else
          {
            bookmark.find("i").removeClass("success_green");
            bookmark.find("i").addClass("gray");
          }
        },
        error:function(data)
        {
          $('input[name="fmpfy_tk"]').val(data.csrf);
        }
      });
    });
  })
  </script>
```

Comment: are you sure data.response is 'on'?

Comment: Yes, just added an alert to check the response and it is "on" or "off" depending on bookmarking and un-bookmarking.

Answer (score 0):

Oops on my part, I was using the wrong css class for the color change. This code works fine.